# How to get into Recovery mode in MacOS 11.4 **Remotely**(M1)

Tags: startup, recovery, apple-silicon, sip

I need to reboot into recovery mode on a **remote** Mac machine (M1, 11.4). I found that there are 2 ways to do it: One - By pressing some buttons at startup. Two - By setting the nvram like so:

```
sudo nvram "recovery-boot-mode=unused"
```

But the latter gives me this error:

```
nvram: Error setting variable - 'recovery-boot-mode': (iokit/common) not permitted
```

I read that is something to do with SIP. But this exactly what I'm trying to change in recovery...
So I'm in an endless loop :(

Any help is welcomed.

Comment: Even if you manage to get the Mac to boot into Recovery, how do you intend to login afterwards?